# error message during installation of numpy package

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am new to python. I am trying to install numpy and matplotlib packages in pycharm. But it shows error. I am attaching the screenshot. How to resolve this?

Thanks
Alok

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately, we can see the screenshot, I think you don't have that privilege as a new user. The question would be a better it on the Super User StackExchange site, being about software.

Comment: Show the error please.